# Остановка события на родителе

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, есть проблема с дублированием аналогичных событий на мобильных устройствах. При тесте на ПК все отрабатывает корректно, но на телефоне срабатывают события родителя:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<script>
  $(".parent")
    .on('touchstart', this, function(event){
      // код не должен срабатывать при клике на потомка
      // но должен срабатывать на касании на родителе
      alert('Ошибка!');
    })
    .on("touchend", this, function(event){
      // код не должен срабатывать при клике на потомка
      // но должен срабатывать на касании на родителе
      alert('Ошибка!');
    });

  $(".child")
    .on('click', function(event){
      // тут код должен исполнится
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к. сначала срабатывали события touchstart и touchend, то решение проблемы нашел через добавление таймера.
Обработка touchstart не приводила к нарушению логики, поэтому сделал обработку только touchend:

```
var clickTimer;
$(".parent")
  .on("touchend", function(event){
    clearTimeout(clickTimer);
    clickTimer = setTimeout(touchend_function, 50);
  });

$(".child")
  .on('click', function(event){
    clearTimeout(clickTimer);
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
```